# Image post: which algebraic technique is being deployed here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Can someone identify this "trick" so I can come to understand its derivation and perhaps put it to use? It looks like we're dealing with the difference of two squares, but that's about as far as I can proceed.

Comment: You're thinking in the right direction. First, put the two numbers on equal denominator, then use the formula for the difference of two squares, then look at the equation again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like this derivation skipped a lot of steps, so I'm just going to complete it. Basically, the trick is difference of squares formula.

First, put everything under one denominator:

$$b^2-\frac{(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2}{4c^2}=\frac{4b^2c^2-(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2}{4c^2}$$

Now, notice that $4b^2c^2$ is just $(2bc)^2$. This way, the numerator becomes a difference of squares.

$$\frac{(2bc)^2-(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2}{4c^2}$$

Now, apply the difference of squares formula (and then distribute negative sign):

$$\frac{(b^2+c^2-a^2+2bc)(2bc-(b^2+c^2-a^2))}{4c^2}=\frac{(b^2+c^2-a^2+2bc)(2bc-b^2-c^2+a^2)}{4c^2}$$

$b^2+c^2+2bc=(b+c)^2$. Also, $2bc-b^2-c^2=-(b^2+c^2-2bc)=-(b-c)^2$. Now, substitute in order to get two more difference of squares:

$$\frac{(b+c)^2-a^2)(a^2-(b-c)^2)}{4c^2}$$

Now, apply the difference of squares formula (and then distribute negative signs/rearrange terms)

$$\frac{(b+c+a)(b+c-a)(a+b-c)(a-(b-c))}{4c^2}=\frac{(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)}{4c^2}$$

Thus, we have gotten to the point where your picture has in the derivation.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you tremendously.